# Are Church encoded sum types a proper alternative in an untyped language?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, discriminated-union, church-encoding

I have been struggling for quite some time with the idea of sum types in Javascript. The language includes neither native sum types nor pattern matching. While you can mimic sum types with plain old Javascript `Object`s and the prototype system and introduce a primitive form of pattern matching (duck typing and branching via `switch`) the approach is tedious and the result looks anything but idiomatic - at least in my view.

So I came up with the idea to use church encoding for expressing sum types - however, not in a strict fashion, i.e. language features like conditional operator etc. are allowed. I implemented the option type as an exercise:

```
const some = a => _ => f => f(a);
const none =      x => _ => x

const head = xs => 0 in xs ? some(xs[0]) : none;

head(["foo"]) ("") (x => x.toUpperCase()); // "FOO"
head([]) ("") (x => x.toUpperCase()); // ""
```

First of all, I am not sure if this is a correct implementation. Beyond that two things bother me:

- I am not certain if there is an appropriate default value for all possible scenarios. `""` is the neutral element for `String`s - but is there such an element like neutral or zero for any type?
- since `head` now returns a binary function, it isn't composable anymore

Apart from that, I find this approach very promising, since it depends solely on higher order functions and doesn't introduce fancy new types, which are somehow alien to the language.

Is Chruch encoding just a nice intellectual challenge or is the technique capable of solving real problems?

Sorry if this question is too broad or confused or both, but I feel like in a dead end.

Comment: I don't see what you need an "appropriate default value" for. You can implement every `Option` operator on your representation (e.g. `maybe = id`, `isJust = m => m(false)(_ => true)`, `fmap = g => m => (x => f => m(x)(a=>f(g(a))))`)

Comment: What makes higher-order functions uncomposable? `head` is still a function that takes one list parameter and returns one option value.

Comment: @Bergi I see. The main argument that is shared by the composition is a function as well, with `r -> (a -> r) -> r` as its type. It still confuses me as soon as functions are used as data. I should finally get used to it.

Comment: @Bergi Ah, I can of course define `map`/`ap`/`chain` and thus do not need to "unbox" the value. I should think twice before asking!

Comment: @Bergi Why do you additionally pass `x` and `f` to `fmap`? You only need an `x` when you unwrap the `Option`. And you don't need an `f` either, because `fmap` is specific to `Option` anyway. Couldn't we simplify the code to `fmap = g => m => m(None) (x => Some(g(x)))`. The type would still be `(a -> b) -> (r -> (a -> r)) -> (r -> (b -> r)) -> r`. Or am I not allowed to use `Some`/`None` inside `fmap` with Church and this is actually Scott?

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I just had written it out without thinking about alternatives. Calling `m` immediately is indeed more efficient (less memory bound by closure) and elegant. Using `None` and `Some` is no problem, you could have written them out as well. Regarding Scott vs Church, I've not yet fully comprehended [the difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mogensen–Scott_encoding#Comparison_to_the_Church_encoding)

Answer (score 0):

For one, in Smalltalk, with its "really everything is an object" approch, [booleans and conditionals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk#Code_blocks) are not language constructs, but represented by Church booleans (although nobody calls them like that, I think). A Smalltalk boolean is an object accepting two messages (aka "having two methods") `ifTrue:` and `ifFalse:`, which are then handled depending on which of `true` or `false` the object actually is.

Furthermore, there's a JS library called [daggy](https://github.com/fantasyland/daggy) to tagged sums, which internally uses something like Church encoding: it encodes sum types as something it calls [catamorphisms](https://github.com/fantasyland/daggy/blob/67bd910a0a5239f3696dd0597315905375e8d8a8/src/daggy.js#L56), which are actually just functions selecting the right tag, although there's a bit more around that, dealing with JS specifities.

Comment: I see, `cata` is their way to automatically create `bool`, `maybe` etc. daggy is a funny name, btw. Interestingly, the type of `maybe` is `b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b`, which is pretty close to `some` in my example: `a ->  r -> (a -> r) -> r`. Thanks for the examples.